# P4: How do I merge several calls of "p4 integrate" into a single changelist (in a batch-file)?

Tags: batch-file, perforce

I'm trying to write a batch file that integrates several branches. I'd like to have one changelist that contains all the changes.

My initial idea was to create the changelist first and then use that one for the integration. But it seems to me that this is hardly possible.
Instead it appears that you need to integrate first and then create a changelist. According to the [p4 help](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_change.html):

> All files open in the default changelist are moved to the new changelist.

I don't like this this approach, but the thing is that it does not even work. My batch looks like this:

```
p4 integrate //source1/... //target1/...
p4 integrate //source2/... //target2/...
p4 integrate //source3/... //target3/...

p4 resolve -am -c default

p4 change -i < changelistInfo.txt
```

And the result is that I've got a new **but empty** changelist and all integrations are still in the default changelist.
That's in clear contrast to what the help says.

I'm totally stuck here. How can I make sure that all integrations are moved to a changelist? If possible, without putting them into the default changelist first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your pending changelist, use the form generated for you by "p4 change -o", e.g.:

```
p4 change -o | sed -e "s/<.*>/My Description/" | p4 change -i
```

The changelist form generated by "p4 change -o" includes the list of files for the changelist (by default this is all files in the default changelist), and when "p4 change -i" reads the form it looks at that list; if there are no files in there, it creates a changelist without any files.

If you're writing a batch script on Windows the challenging part is editing the form on the fly like I did with 'sed' in the above example; I'm on Windows and I handle stuff like this by having the Cygwin tools (sed, grep, cut, etc) in my %path% so I can run commands like that from the cmd prompt, batch files, etc.

Comment: So, it took me a while to get it working as I didn't use the cygwin tools and instead figured out how to read/write the file via pure batch. I've posted the eventual outcome in another answer but accepted this one as it was the key to solution. Btw, I'm flagging the comments above as obsolete as they're just redundant information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to assemble your pending work in the changelist of your choice.

Since you'd prefer not to work in the default changelist first, that's what you should do:

1. First, create your (empty) pending changelist by running `p4 change -i < changelistDescription.txt`
2. Note your changelist number. `p4 change -i` prints it out for you, or you can get it after the fact by doing something like `p4 changes -s pending -u Em1 -m1`. Let's say it's NNN.
3. Next, perform your integrations by running `p4 integrate -c NNN`. Including the '-c NNN' flag tells `p4 integrate` to open the files in that specified numbered changelist, rather than in the default changelist. After each integrate command, the newly opened files will be accumulated in that numbered changelist, which you can confirm by running `p4 opened`.
4. Then you can run `p4 resolve` just as you were before. If you specify '-c' to `p4 resolve`, make sure that you specify the same changelist number '-c NNN', but in general I'd say just omit the '-c' flag to `p4 resolve`.

While you're developing your script, I recommend closely reading the output of each command as you develop and test it, and also sprinkling your script with commands like `p4 opened` or `p4 status` so you can see what each command has changed in your workspace.

Comment: Well, I've seen that it prints out the changelist number. But how do I obtain that number in a script. I don't want to type in the proper change number by hand. And p4 integrate doesn't have something like -m1. I could write it into a file, parse the file, get the number, I don't know how complicated a script could be...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on [the answer of Sam Stafford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31996439/779395), but I didn't use cygwin tools. So here's my code that is completely pure batch.

```
p4 integrate //source1/... //target1/...
p4 integrate //source2/... //target2/...
p4 integrate //source3/... //target3/...

SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

p4 change -o > temp.txt

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in (temp.txt) do (
    set foo=%%a
    set foo=!foo:^<enter description here^>=Merging!
    echo !foo! >> changelist.txt)

p4 resolve -am -c default
p4 change -i < changelist.txt

del temp.txt
del changelist.txt
```

Instead of calling a cygwin single line command, I iterate over each line to change the default description text. This is a bit more code but has the same effect.
And it requires deleting the files. But other than that, there's nothing different to the other solution.